# Providing a template for $confirm dialogs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, confirm

I'm using angular-confirm to display confirmation messages in a lot of places in my app.  For example:

```
$confirm({
    text: 'content',
    title: 'title text',
    ok: 'Yes',
    cancel: 'No'})
.then(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

I want to globally change the layout in which these dialogs appear in the app.  I know that angular-confirm allows you to make a global change like this:

```
$confirmModalDefaults.templateUrl = 'path/to/your/template';
```

However, this also overrides the template for all $modal.open() calls, which is not what I want.

I think that the way to do this is by a using a provider to append a template url to every $confirm call in the app but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

How do I create a provider for $confirm and append a templateUrl parameter to every call?

Comment: What version of angular-bootstrap you use? You can check in source https://github.com/Schlogen/angular-confirm/blob/master/angular-confirm.js that angular-confirm does nothing with modal defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$confirm', confirmProvider);
}

/* @ngInject */
function confirmProvider($delegate) {
    return function (data, settings) {
        if (settings && !settings.template && !settings.templateUrl) {
            settings.template = '<div>my confirm content</div>';
    } else {
        settings = {
            template: '<div>my confirm content</div>'
        }
    }

    return $delegate(data, settings);
};
```

So now, when $confirm() gets called with data and/or settings, it will apply my custom template unless it's been specified by the caller